# Formula for counting loop iteration

Tags: java, loops

I have spent so much time trying to find the formula for this code, but still nothing .. I know the running time but the question really is, what if n = 100 for example, how many line of output will this code print? Is there any specific formula to get the count? The code I've done:

```
int i, j, k;

for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    for (j = i + 1; j <= n; j++) {
        for (k = j + 1; k <= n; k++) {
            System.out.println(i + " " + j + " " + k);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what "FORMULA" are you referring to? What is the problem statement? By the way the runtime complexity of above code is $O(n^3)$.

Comment: How can I find how many lines of output the above code would print without tracing through it ?

Comment: if n = 10, it will be 120 lines of output

Comment: multiplying i * j * k won't be right too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a feeling that you are requiring a **formula** to get number of iteration the nested loops will.

```
  for( i = 1; i <= n; i++ )
     for ( j = i+1; j <= n; j++ )
        for( k = j+1; k <= n; k++ )
```

For those loops, the number of iterations will be:

```
(n*(n-1)*(n-2))/6, where n > 2.
```

**Generic formula** for above kind nested loops:

```
(n*(n-1)* ... *(n-r+1)) / r!, where n > r-1.
```

Here, r = number of nested loops

For example: when n = 20 and r = 3, number of iterations will be = (20*19*18) / 3! = 1140

Comment: I can't thank you enough, spent literally 5 hours trying to figure out pattern to this formula. One more thing, this is one of the summation rules, right ?

Comment: I'd prefer to put: (n*(n-1)*(n-2))/(!3). Now I don't know what the summation rules are, but it sounds correct since this is equivalent to saying where n = 5, count = 3+2+1+2+1+1

Comment: @AhmedLo yes, kind of.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly, *i < j < k*. What's more, *1 ≤ i < j < k ≤ n*.
Or in other words, the number of lines printed is the number of different unordered sets of 3 different numbers from a total set of n numbers. You can continue from here.

Hint: combination

Comment: thought about combination, but in term of time complexity how I translate that to formula ..?

Comment: Erm... use a combination formula?